# Scroll window to center along the y-axis using Prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have an element which I want to put in the center of the screen along the y-axis. This is what I have so far:

```
window.scrollTo(0, (document.viewport.getHeight() / 2) - $$('.my-elems-class')[0].getHeight());
```

Thing is, its on different locations on different screens. How could that be?

Thanks fpr helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The x-axis will be 0;
for y-axis to be half. try this

```
var element_top = $$('.my-elems-class:first').offset().top;

var documentHeight = window.innerHeight;
documentHeight = documentHeight ? documentHeight : Math.min(document.documentElement.clientHeight, document.body.clientHeight);

var y_axis = element_top - (documentHeight/2);
```

So now use

```
window.scrollTo(0, y_axis);
```

Comment: Thanks, but does that take my element into account?

Comment: Ill try in about an hour, have something else on my list first. But thanks so far!

Comment: Yes, works as expected. I replaced offset() with cumulativeOffset() because I needed it for Prototype, rest works fine, thanks!